# i am trying to run this code and getting error AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium4

tring this codebut throwing an attribute error
driver: WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

```
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")
driver.find_element_by_name("txtUsername").send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element_by_id("txtPassword").send_keys("admin123")
driver.find_element_by_id("btnLogin").click()

act_title=driver.title
exp_title="OrangeHRM"

if act_title==exp_title:
    print("Login test pass")
else:
    print("Login test fail")

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
```

There is no need to declare WebDriver as driver.

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute for the User Name element is `username`.

The name attribute for the Password element is `password`.

Otherwise, you can use other locators like `xpath` like -

```
//input[@placeholder='Username']
```

Answer (score 0):

All the methods like `find_element_by_name`, `find_element_by_xpath`, `find_element_by_id` etc. are deprecated now.
You should use `find_element(By.` instead.
So, your code can be as following:

```py
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "txtUsername").send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtPassword").send_keys("admin123")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnLogin").click()

act_title=driver.title
exp_title="OrangeHRM"

if act_title==exp_title:
    print("Login test pass")
else:
    print("Login test fail")

driver.close()
```

Also, you should add delays in the above code. `WebDriverWait` should be used for that

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing wrong attribute that is not on the webpage or maybe you have written name of attributes and there value
try CSS selector or XPath
Example:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//TagName[@attribute='value']"));
or
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(""));